# Curl request for ASP page

Tags: php, asp.net, forms, post, curl

A web page I am working on loads this page (http://www.homeinsight.com/Widget/default.asp?RP6TQO4W8S84) into an iframe.  There is a button that says "Next" in a form on the page.  When the user clicks "Next" the form submits.  It calls itself according to the action attribute on the form. The page that returns is step two.

I have changed the iframe so that it loads a php file which requests the same page as above with cURL.  I also adjusted the form's Action attribute so that it calls a php file which does a cURL request for the page (http://www.homeinsight.com/Widget/default.asp?RP6TQO4W8S84).  My problem is that I am not able to get Step 2 to appear when I submit the form through the cURL request.  How can I get the cURL request to submit the inputs so that step 2 will appear?

Using HttpFox and Tamper Data, I found that the only Post variables are
    [firstName] => Yourfirstname
    [lastName] => Yourlastname
    [emailAddress] => someemail@adomain.biz
    [phone] => 9433238999
    [Iam] => Sell-Home
    [next_x] => 30
    [next_y] => 19
    [PostBack] => 1
    [QueryString] => RP6TQO4W8S84
    [GCID] => Direct

Here is the php code that I am using to make the request for the ASP page with the posted inputs from the Step 1 form.

```
<?php

function getUrlContent($url, $postedVarsMinus1 = NULL)
{
    //open connection - initialize cURL handler
    $ch = curl_init();

    //set fieds to be posted
    //postedVarsMinus1 is an array of all the post variables that were
    //passed into the php code minus one post variable I added
    if(!is_null($postedVarsMinus1))
    {
        $fields = $postedVarsMinus1;
    }
    else
    {
        $fields = "";
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); //true

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    $contentType = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
    curl_close($ch);

    return ($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300) ? array($result, $contentType) : false;
}
?>
```

Comment: I tried the following command: `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"firstName":"Matt"}' http://www.homeinsight.com/Widget/default.asp?RP6TQO4W8S84` and got these [results](http://imgur.com/gallery/Wc3h2N6/new)

Comment: That is the Step 1 page.  Step 2 asks about street address.

Comment: Do you have access to edit the ASP? If you do you can print out the values received from cURL

Comment: I am unable to edit the ASP.  I was using cURL to make the iframe on the same domain so I could use php and JS to to edit HTML's appearance.

Comment: Does step 2 use the same URL for the cURL?

Comment: Step 1's form goes to http://www.homeinsight.com/Widget/default.asp?RP6TQO4W8S84.  Which is the same URL that is originally loaded into the iframe to get Step 1.  Step 2's form goes to a different URL.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what the back-end code expects as far as values (does it need the form name and the name of the next button)? I've thrown together a quick example, but it's not 100% working since I'm guessing the code behind on the ASP checks a few other details. So I'll give you a general outline of what you need to do:

1) pull the form in via `cURL` (which you've done)

2) Modify the form attribute to a file on *your* server (I chose to use jQuery)

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('form').attr('action', 'myaction.php');
    });
</script>
```

3) Create the form action file (myaction.php):

```
$first = $_POST['firstName'];
$last = $_POST['lastName'];
$email = $_POST['emailAddress'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$iam = $_POST['Iam'];
$pb = $_POST['PostBack'];
$qs = $_POST['QueryString'];
$gcid = $_POST['GCID'];

$data = array('firstName' => $first, 'lastName' => $last, 'emailAddress' => $email, 'phone' => $phone, 'Iam' => $iam, 'PostBack' => $pb, 'QueryString' => $qs, 'GCID' => $gcid);

getUrlContent('http://www.homeinsight.com/Widget/default.asp?RP6TQO4W8S84', $data);
```

Comment: I have done that.  However, the html that I get back is for Step 1 again.

Comment: yeah that's what happened to me as well. I'm guessing the ASP is expecting some more data in `POST` that I/you haven't passed. Did you pass the form name/next button name along with your post data?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all who posted their advice.  Matt Altepeter's post affirmed that what I was doing should have worked.  However, I was missing a step that cURL or the website thought was necessary.

I used a site in which I could construct my own post complete with parameters.  That site returned the correct page information.  It also gave me the post fields in the form of a string, which gave me the idea that curl or the site to which I was submitting did not like my array of variables.  Subsequently I urlencoded all the values in my array and converted my array to a string of the form key1=value1&key2=value2& etc.  I then put that string as my post fields variable.  Works!!